# How to Hide First Item of h3:before

Tags: css

I have multiple H3 headings on a page. I wanted to display a black line before each H3 on the page except the first h3 and I have implemented following rule:

```
#Webappcontent_2346 > h3:before {
margin: 0 auto;
content: "";
width: 98%;
height: 1px;
border: none;
background: #000;
display: inline-block;
}
```

This rule displays black line before each h3, however I'm not sure which rule I can use to hide the line before first h3.

Any ideas?

Comment: What browser are you hoping this to work on?

Comment: I'm targeting all major browsers. Btw, nth-of-type(1):before also worked. Thanks for the replies. For some reason, I find answers to my questions after posting my question here :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use :

```
#Webappcontent_2346 > h3:not(:first-child) {
   margin: 0 auto;
   content: "";
   width: 98%;
   height: 1px;
   border: none;
   background: #000;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
h3:not(:first-child)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the first-of-type selector

```
h3:not(:first-of-type)
```

Answer (score 0):

[check this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d7qt3vq4/)

```
#Webappcontent_2346 > h3:first-child:before {display:none}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Demo below:

```css
h1:not(:first-child){
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```